# How to output single page html and docx?

Tags: gitbook

How can I output a single page html and docx? I see references to single page html in older versions but not to the current release. I don't see anything relating to word doc/docx format. How do I export to these formats?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to download the Gitbook CLI Toolchain according to the instructions here: https://toolchain.gitbook.com

- Clone your gitbook to your local machine
- Run `gitbook build` to, in essence, "convert" the .md files of your book to .html
- Open the `_book` folder (which is it output from the `gitbook build` command)
- Find the .html in question.

As far as .docx solutions...don't know